# XtreReport displaying second empty page when my first page content is less ? Winforms Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, report, xtrareport

I used three DetailReports and a PageFooter. Less number of data only available in my 1st page, but when I preview or run the program it show two pages why ? Already my first page fill  less content only. Whats wrong in my code ?

Comment: Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: I think that one of your controls in the report is outside of page boundries

Comment: If you ask "Whats wrong in my code?" you should show us some code :D I think it will be the problem @MilenPavlov described but some code would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem appears if some report elements (labels, tables) exceed the page's width and overlap onto the right page margin. XtraReports renders the right part of such elements on a new page. You should either decrease the right margin of your report or resize the report elements so that they all fit into the width of a single page. There is no programmatic solution for this problem. 
Moreover on closer inspection of a less complex report, you may notice the red "page" icon indicating that.